# Particle effect continues to loop even with looping off and "Destroy" set as the stop action

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, particles

I have a particle effect set to play on click. It's a muzzle flash for a gun. It continues to loop once I fire for the first time despite looping being turned off. I have a `public ParticleSystem muzzleFlash;` at the beginning of my script and inside of my `Shoot` method I have `muzzleFlash.Play();`

Comment: You'll need to give us all the steps to reproduce this problem in a new, empty project for us to be able to isolate the cause and test solutions to be sure they work.

Comment: Ok thank you I appreciate the feedback